# CRON script timing out on AWS ubuntu -- php.ini files look good, where else should I check? (timeout)

Tags: php, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, cron

I have a cron script which calls a PHP file every minute.  That file checks to see if any actions need to be taken and, if so, takes those actions.  When the execution time is long, however, this script doesn't always finish.  I'm not seeing any error codes, and my built-in logging simply stops, since it only runs with the file being executed.

The thing is: the amount of time varies over a dozen seconds in range, so I'm not sure if it's 300 seconds to my timeout when sometimes the script seems to quit after just 280.

This is being run on an AWS ubuntu server.

Is there a list of all the places I might check for errors or timeouts?  The two php.ini files are both set to a half-hour, and my script is not running for nearly that long.

Comment: What does that PHP file do?

Comment: It can do a bunch of things, but the execution timeout is occurring during a sync with a third party's API, though I don't think that's at all relayed.

Comment: Do you see any thing in var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: There is no apache log; this server is running nginx, and nothing is appended to it upon the termination of the PHP script (just test again to confirm)

Comment: Increase php script execution time in nginx by going here vim /etc/nginx/nginx.conf and adding this code in http section "fastcgi_read_timeout 300; "